# Inheriting from a parent class in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

When you inherit from a parent class in python 3.x does the parent class 'empty' its default values, and do you have to re-define them?

Comment: How did it go when you tried it?

Comment: Well I'm sort of just starting out, and going through this stuff in theory. So no.

Comment: All right, fair enough, but go try it out and if you still don't understand please post :)

Comment: @limelights: He who asks a questions is a fool for a few minutes. He who doesn't ask dies a fool. :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla I agree whole heartedly! I didn't tell him NOT to ask questions just asked him to try it out and see what happens. I encourage questions, what I don't encourage is help vampires. But if I offended the OP, i am indeed sorry! It was meant as a helpful pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Software should try to be consistent. So if you split a class into methods and fields, they should still behave similarly. For methods, you expect to inherit them from your parent without any modifications unless you can see such a modification in the child.

For symmetry, fields behave the same: Unless you overwrite them in the child, you will get what the parent defines.

From a more practical perspective, computers are always too slow. So software tries to avoid unnecessary work. When you inherit from a parent, as little as possible is changed.

[This article](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html) gives a lot of insight how inheritance works in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Any methods not overridden in the child are looked for in the parents. This includes the initializer, `__init__()`. If you do not define this in the child then the parent's method is called, initializing the object as it would an instance of the parent.